# vba error 1004 in calculating binomial distribution using double for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I wanted to write down a simple piece of code for implementing a double summation of binomial distribution product. The code I have written is:

```
Sub reactiveTransshipment()

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
Dim y1 As Integer
y1 = 1037
Dim y2 As Integer
y2 = 1037

Dim PI1 As Double
PI1 = 0
Dim PI1_1 As Double
PI1_1 = 0
Dim PI1_2 As Double
PI1_2 = 0

Dim k1 As Double
Dim k2 As Double

Dim n As Integer
n = 2000
Dim P As Double
P = 0.5

For j = 0 To (y2 - 1)
    For i = (y1 + 1) To (y1 + y2 - j)
        k1 = WorksheetFunction.BinomDist(i, n, P, False)
        k2 = WorksheetFunction.BinomDist(j, n, P, False)
        PI1_2 = PI1_2 + (k1 * k2)
    Next i
Next j

Worksheets(2).Range("D2").Value = k1

End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above code ?

Comment: Your first `BinomDist` call loops so that `i` (number of successes) is eventually greater than `n` (the number of tests).  The function returns an error because it is not possible to have more successes than tests.  Check your `i` for loop.